# how to display different currencies symbols in android?

Tags: android

i want to display different currencies symbols in combo box(Spinner).
The currencies may me follows:

```
usa
euro
pounds
```

e.t.c

i preferred to read these symbols from the xml. is there any code for the currencies symbols.

how can i do it?

thanks